# call java methods from C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I want to access java method from C++ using JNI.
I try this code it can't find the class file of java. I got the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Example like that

JAVA code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example().printHelloWorld();
    }

    public void printHelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

C++ code is

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    // create JNI environment
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    char optionString[] = "-Djava.class.path=";
    options[0].optionString = optionString;
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &args);

    // find class of Java method
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Example");
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        env->ExceptionClear();
        return 1;
    }
    // get method ID of Java method
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "printHelloWorld", "()V");
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        env->ExceptionClear();
        return 1;
    }
    // call Java method
    jobject obj = env->AllocObject(cls);
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid);
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        env->ExceptionClear();
        return 1;
    }
    // clean up and exit
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't find the error.

Comment: You forgot to set `args.nOptions = 1`

Comment: oh thanks . I have also another doubt ,I want to check the classpath on environmental variable in above code .How can do that

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scapix](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix) to automatically generate Java bindings directly from C++ header files.

Disclaimer: I am the author of [Scapix](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix) project.